# Deploy multiple artifacts to Gigaspaces at the same time

Tags: maven, deployment, xap, gigaspaces

I have quite a complicated structure in my project, which consists of 7 **independent** artifacts, which are now deployed with bash script:

```
$GS_DISTR/bin/gs.sh -initialization-timeout 15000 deploy -properties embed://properties.location=/some/path/to/pu.properties -sla file://$TARGET_DIR/sla-artifact-name.xml -override-name new-name $TARGET_DIR/path/to/artficat.j[w]ar
```

We have 7 such lines. Due to `-initialization-timeout` the whole project deploys for long time. I know that Gigaspaces can deploy several artifacts at the same time, respecting their order/dependencies.

I have found no information or guide on official wiki or docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've researched this topic and find solution with `deploy-application`, not `deploy` and it seems to work so far.

More can be found here: http://fau.im/deploy-several-artifacts-to-gigaspaces-simultanious/